# load data infile question

Tags: php, sql, mysql, load-data-infile

I'm currently using LOAD DATA INFILE in my query, but I am not sure how to separate the data

The data is in the following format firstname:lastname

```
$this->db->query("LOAD DATA INFILE 'names.txt' 
                  INTO names firstname lastname 
                FIELDS TERMINATED BY ':'");
```

How would I use this to take the data from the text file and split firstname:lastname to insert firstname into firstname & lastname into lastname?

Comment: Did you try to execute the command "load data " that you have mentioned above?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your table name is `names`. In which case the query should be:

```
"LOAD DATA INFILE 'names.txt' 
    INTO TABLE names
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ':' 
    (firstname, lastname)"
```

Then of course you have to execute the statement.

Also take care of newline characters, field enclosure characters and field escape characters, for which you specify `[LINES] TERMINATED BY`, `[FIELDS] ENCLOSED BY` and `[FIELDS] ESCAPED BY` respectively (square brackets meaning that you only specify `LINES` or `FIELDS` once).